# pass ajax variabel to other php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my **ajax.php**

I try to pass source1 to other php I got error when I use

`$data = json_decode($_POST['source1']);`
It says `Undefined index`. What should I do?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$data = json_decode($_POST['source1']);

 ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <title></title>
</head>
<!-- <form action="sendinto.php" method="post"><center>

<button id="btnSelectedRows" type="button">test send</button>
</center>
</form> -->

<center>
      <button id="btnSelectedRows" >test</button>
    <!-- input type="submit" name="upload" value="Compare"> -->
  </center>
<body>





</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
```

this is my **ajax code**

```
$('#btnSelectedRows').on('click', function() {
 $.post({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'sendinto.php',
  datatype : 'text',
  data: {source1 : "heyo"} ,
   // or GET

}).done(function(data) {
    //Redirect to another page if you want...
    window.location.href = "sendinto.php";
   });
  });
```

this is my **sendinto.php**

```
<?php 

  session_start();
  $coba = $_SESSION['source1'];
  echo $coba;
```

?>

Comment: `$coba = $_POST['source1'];`

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong, as per your source code, you are sending source1 to sendinto.php and trying to access in ajax.php. first, remove the following lines from ajax.php

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $data = json_decode($_POST['source1']);
?>
```

and put it in sendinto.php like:

```
 <?php 
  session_start();
    $data=null;
   //you first need to check it
   if(isset($_POST['source1']))
   $data = json_decode($_POST['source1']);
 ?>
```

Comment: it works, but there is error in sendinto.php

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it

Comment: i already use your code but `$data` return null it mean the ajax not passing the variabel?

Answer (score 0):

you can use if condition for stop error

```
if($_POST['source1']){
   $data = json_decode($_POST['source1']);
}else{
   $data = "";
}
```

Comment: and what i should write in sendinto.php?

Comment: you can simply fetch data in sendinto.php like this                                             
$value = $_POST['source1'];echo $value;

Comment: @SherlinTjoa  if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer.